# Cant get wrapper div right

Tags: html, css

I want a div with some text in it.
In that div I also want a div that matches the same position and proportion.
I found multiple things on stackoverflow but as soon as on thing is different it doesn't work for me.

Right now, I can't see the text anymore. Why?
It would be great if the solution doesn't affect the css for '#container'.

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <p>Somt text to screw with me</p>
    <div class="background-img"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#container {
    position: fixed;
    left: 10px;
    top: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
}

p {
   color: blue; 
}


.background-img {
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/420/255);    
}
```

for the fiddlers:
https://jsfiddle.net/clankill3r/8kaLj2su/

Comment: FYI `background-repeat` should be `: no-repeat` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat

Comment: also there's no need to set `no-repeat` to a background image which has the `cover` background-size.

Comment: thanks for spotting that.

Answer (score 3):

Add `z-index: -1` to your background image.

https://jsfiddle.net/8kaLj2su/2/

Comment: THANKS! I tried changing the z-index of p and the background image to higher values then 0 but it had no effect. Guess I either had to change p to relative like Deepak David solution. But I prefer yours.

Answer (score 2):

A proper way to do it would be **Don't use z-index at all**

Change the logical order of your elements:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="background-img"></div>
    <p>Somt text to screw with me</p>
</div>
```

And than simply set your `p` to relative:

```css
#container {
    position: fixed;
    left: 10px;
    top: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
}

p {
   color: blue; 
    position:relative;
}

.background-img {
    position: absolute;
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/420/255) 50% / cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="background-img"></div>
    <p>Somt text to screw with me</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I like both your answers better than mine. Also why do you recommend not using z-index?

Comment: It's not exactly right that we're not using z-index..just that @Roko was adjusting the structure so that the **natural** `z-index` would work automatically without you having to set it. In my solution, I couldn't see a reason for the absolutely positioned div but there are times it's a viable option.

Comment: Setting the p to relative is irrelevant in this instance. The p position would be relative to the parent #container (which is fixed), not to the sibling div. That would not affect the layering of the text over the image under these circumstances. So this answer is actually somewhat misleading.

Answer (score 1):

```
p {
   color: blue; 
z-index:1;
position:relative;
}
```

Basically Z-index:1 will push the text on top and Position is necessary for z-index to work in most cases. I would not suggest -1 as incase if you have any text for that div it may be hidden too.

Comment: you could improve your response with a comment on what you are doing here

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see your background image with text:

https://jsfiddle.net/xeyw0hvc/

Code:

```
#container {
position: fixed;
left: 10px;
top: 30px;
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
background: red;
z-index:10;
}

p {
color: blue; 
}


.background-img {
position: absolute;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: none;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: url('http://lorempixel.com/420/255');
z-index:-1;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use z-index to select which element overlays the other.

Working example: 
([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8kaLj2su/6/))

```css
#container {
    position: fixed;
    left: 10px;
    top: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
}

p {
   color: blue; 
    z-index:2;
    position:relative;
}


.background-img {
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/420/255); 
    z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <p>Somt text to screw with me</p>
    <div class="background-img"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p {
    color: blue;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: For a good qualitative answer, please add some explanation as to what you changed and why this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Using z-index, like others have suggested is fine. But I have found z-indexing to be a bit buggy, especially on legacy browsers such as older versions of IE. I would approach this differently. Change the order of your markup, make the parent container position:relative, then make both of the child elements position:absolute. That way you avoid using z-index altogether.

Like so: https://jsfiddle.net/4x5nkwgb/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="background-img"></div>
    <p>Somt text to screw with me</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    top: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
}

p {
    color: blue; 
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:block;
}


.background-img {
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/420/255);    
}
```